# urls within the WordPress theme directory are being redirected/broken

Tags: wordpress, localhost

I have several WordPress websites setup locally using MAMP. Suddenly one of them is not displaying correctly. The rest are working fine.

The stylesheet link and other urls within the theme directory look right in the source code but are being redirected somehow thus breaking the links.

For example: http://localhost:8888/site-name/wp-content/themes/theme-name/style.css

redirect to: https://www.localhost:8888/theme-name/style.css

It acts the same way with the default TwentySeventeen theme and I have several database versions setup and they produce the same results.

I have tried everything I can think of to fix this. Hopefully someone can help point me in the right direction.

Comment: check your htaccess fileand option table home and site url

Comment: Thanks @dipmala these are good suggestions but I already checked them. The htaccess file only has the basic wordpress entries and the home and site url are correct. I even tried defining   WP_CONTENT_URL, WP_HOME, and WP_SITEURL in wp-config. It still redirects. It does this even if you put the css url directly in the browser address bar.